# Magento2 - How to get Image Size?

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.4

For Image optimisation, I want't to get Product Image Size. (Either in KB or MB etc.)

[image]

Ex: 6 KB, 6KB,5KB etc.

I am using following code on **root** path.

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$product_collections = $instance ->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collections = $product_collections->create();
$i = 0;
foreach ($collections as $product) {

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $productObj = $productRepository->get($product->getSku());

    echo "<b>".$productObj->getName()."</b>";    
        echo "<br>";

        $i++;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $mediaPath = $directory->getPath('media');

    $product_id = $productObj->getId();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

    $galleryReadHandler = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler');
    $galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

        foreach($images as $image){
            echo "<pre>";print_r($image);echo "</pre>";
         $temp = $mediaPath."/catalog/product".$image->getFile();
         //echo "<pre>"; print_r($temp); echo "</pre>";
         echo $temp;
         echo "<br>";
        }    
}
echo "Total Products: ".$i;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to get image size in PHP. But You can get the image size faster by curl with HTTP header request and use the below code in curl request:

```
$imageUrl = 'Your image URL';
$img = get_headers($imageUrl, 1);
print_r($img["Content-Length"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below & It's working.

```
<?php 
$image = 'test.png';
$file_size = filesize($image); // Get file size in bytes
$file_size = $file_size / 1024; // Get file size in KB
$sizeInKb = number_format((float)$file_size, 2, '.', '');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the product images, you can modify your code to calculate the size of each image file. Here's an updated version of your script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$product_collections = $instance->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collections = $product_collections->create();
$i = 0;

foreach ($collections as $product) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $mediaPath = $directory->getPath('media');

    $product_id = $product->getId();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

    $galleryReadHandler = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler');
    $galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $temp = $mediaPath . "/catalog/product" . $image->getFile();
        echo "<b>" . $product->getName() . "</b>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Image: " . $temp;
        echo "<br>";

        // Get image size in bytes
        $imageSize = filesize($temp);

        // Convert bytes to kilobytes
        $imageSizeKB = round($imageSize / 1024, 2);

        echo "Size: " . $imageSizeKB . " KB";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";

        $i++;
    }
}

echo "Total Products: " . $i;
```

This script calculates the size of each image file in kilobytes and displays it along with the image information. Please note that using ObjectManager directly is not recommended, and it's better to use dependency injection for cleaner and more maintainable code.